# Автозапуск события при старте приложения

Tags: java, android

Как можно реализовать автозапуск метода при старте приложения?
Мой метод срабатывающий по кнопке

```
public void OnClickId (View view)
    {
        tvs = tv.getText().toString();
        Zapros1 = new zapros3();
        Zapros1.start(tvs);

        try {
            Zapros1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie)
        {
            Log.e("pass 0 ", ie.getMessage());
        }
        tv.setText(tvs);
        num.setText(nums);


    }
```

Но как сделать его автоматическим при запуске приложения?
Ошибка возникающая при добавлении/вызове в OnCreate

```
2022-02-17 09:28:29.807 29293-29445/com.example.rifar E/pass 1: connection success 
2022-02-17 09:28:29.808 29293-29445/com.example.rifar E/pass 2: connection success  
2022-02-17 09:28:29.808 29293-29445/com.example.rifar E/Fail 3: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 2 of  
2022-02-17 09:28:29.817 29293-29293/com.example.rifar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rifar, PID: 29293
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rifar/com.example.rifar.MainActivityAD}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3539)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3699)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2135)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8037)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.rifar.MainActivityAD.onCreate(MainActivityAD.java:76)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8157)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8129)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3512)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3699) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2135) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8037) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

Решил проблему убрав эти строки

```
 tv.setText(tvs);
 num.setText(nums);
```

Comment: В onCreate запишите

Comment: @ArtyMorris, все работает, но когда когда открываешь activity с этим методом, то приложение вылетает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте onCreate.

как я вижу ваш код начинает работать после нажатия, если вы хотите запустить эту часть кода то используйте в onCreate, либо создайте отдельный метод (например public void имя_метода) и вызовите его в onCreate

Comment: Также стоит учесть что если вы хотите как-то взаимодействовать с View то вам необходимо дождатся когда все View прорисуются на экране. В противном случаи у вас будет возникать ошибка или возвращать значение 0 при запуске приложения. Чтобы начать взаимодействие с View добавьте ему слушатель onGlobalLayoutListener. Вот ответ как это сделать:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49304872/view-getx-and-gety-returns-zero/49305054

Comment: Немного поправлю свой предыдущий комментарии. Всё же некоторые методы можно вызывать и никаких ошибок не будет. Но некоторые могут выдать ошибку или возратить значение 0 (допустим getX())

Comment: При создании метода  `public  void Metod()` скобки подчеркивает красным, прописываешь view все равно ошибка. Попробовал вызвать метод `Metod()` в OnCreate, все рабоатет, но приложение вылетает как только открываешь activity с данным кодом